# Skip last line of csv while loading in hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

Skip Last line of csv while loading in hive table

for first line i got below property

tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");

details.csv Input file load in hive so we get o/p as below (Skip the last Line from the given data)

file: details.csv

Input:

```
Id,Name,age,city
101,ram,26,pune
102,ajay,31,Mum
103,sham,25,pune
104,rani,22,bglr
105,raja,36,Mum
```

Output:

```
Id,Name,age,city
101,ram,26,pune
102,ajay,31,Mum
103,sham,25,pune
104,rani,22,bglr
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: example added now

Comment: can you pls try this `TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.footer.line.count'='1', 'skip.header.line.count'='1')` ?